# Getting the count of table from another table in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to get the count of table from another tables using cakephp3 , but i have get an error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS Transactions__COUNT(*) FROM transactions Transactions LEFT JOIN transactio' at line 1

I don't know what's wrong with my code !!

here's my  controller :

```
  $data = $this->Transactions->find(
        'all', 
        array(
            'fields' => array('COUNT(*)'),
            'group' => array('transactions_type_id'),
            'contain' => array('TransactionsTypes')
             )                );
```

and here's my ctp:

```
 <?php 
                        foreach ($data as $transactionsType) {

                            ?>
             <li>
                <p class="clearfix"><i class="icon-radio-checked text-info"></i><b><?php echo $transactionsType['title'] ?> </b><span>210</span>
                </p>
                <div class="progress progress-md">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="8" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 8%"><span class="sr-only">10% Complete (success)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
             <?php }
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can use `count()` function.

```
$count=TableRegistry::get('Transactions')
    ->find()
    ->contain('TransactionsTypes')
    ->group('Transactions.transactions_type_id')
    ->count();
```

Comment: Thank you for replay , I have tried this but this give me this error 
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template\Pages\home.ctp, line 109]

Comment: the error at this line :
foreach ($count as $transactionsType) {

Comment: Also i have tried var_dump($count) and that give me that 
int(1)

Comment: count() will return the count of rows as int value.
so If you want to get the result too use all() function or first()
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#working-with-result-sets